# Is it possible to load/include a whole angularjs SPA inside a <div> in an Ajax/Jquery page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs

Is it possible to load/include a whole angularjs SPA inside a `<div>` in an Ajax/jQuery page?

Comment: In order to get an answer on stackoverflow, you normally have ask a specific question, and show some code you've used to try to solve your problem yourself. Sometimes you may find posts that are long and in-depth, but you generally won't get a "tutorial" here, just an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible!
Just set your angularJS application with tag ng-app.